# How to obtain the solutions of Solve with same denominator?

Tags: equation-solving

Is it possible to force Solve giving solutions with the same denominator?

For example:

```
sol=Solve[c3 L+(c2 L^2)/2+(c1 L^3)/6+(q L^4)/(24 J Y)==0&&c3+c2 L+(c1 L^2)/2+(q L^4)/(6 J Y)==0&&c2+3 (q L^2)/(5J Y)==0,{c1,c2,c3}]
```

Comment: Please give a concrete example to show what you have tried and what you desire instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

sol = Solve[
   c3 L + (c2 L^2)/2 + (c1 L^3)/6 + (q L^4)/(24 J Y) == 0 && 
    c3 + c2 L + (c1 L^2)/2 + (q L^4)/(6 J Y) == 0 && 
    c2 + 3 (q L^2)/(5 J Y) == 0, {c1, c2, c3}][[1]]

(* {c1 -> -(((-41 L + 20 L^2) q)/(40 J Y)), c2 -> -((3 L^2 q)/(5 J Y)), 
 c3 -> ((21 L^3 + 20 L^4) q)/(240 J Y)} *)

denom = PolynomialLCM @@ (Denominator /@ sol[[All, -1]])

(* 240 J Y *)

sol2 = sol /. (var_ -> RHS_) :> (var -> 
     Inactive[Divide][RHS*denom, denom])
```

[image]

```
sol === (sol2 // Activate)

(* True *)
```

Comment: Thanks. Your solution works if ["Global`*"] works. I cannot use it before the Solve.